# In Django, how to make results of manage.py test go into a file?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

How do I get the results of manage.py test to print into a file? I tried:

```
manage.py test > test.log
```

But for some reason, this only fills the file with

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

And doesn't give me the part with

```
........
----------------------
Ran 8 tests in 0.148s
```

Which is what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is the difference between `stdout` and `stderr`. In your example you redirected only `stdout`. To redirect both you can use this in modern shells:

```
./manage.py test &> test.log
```

Or in older shells you can use:

```
./manage.py test > test.log 2> test.log
```